# Clause confusion

Tags: clauses

I am studying SFL grammar and I have this sentence that I need to break down into clauses and say what type of clauses they are.

> Studies show that when caught by fishermen, sea trout are more likely to be returned to the water than salmon.

I assume that the first part is a projecting clause, but it is the "when caught by fishermen" that perplexes me.

Is it an embedded clause within the projecting clause?
Or is it an embedded 'by'-clause with ellipted participant and process -- "when  caught by fishermen"?

Comment: According to Wikipedia SFL is a "part of a social semiotic approach to language."  Back away slowly but avoid eye contact.  Semioticians can sense fear, and given a chance they will neutralize the higher thought centers of your brain.

Comment: The analysis of "when" is problematic. Some see it as a preposition, others as a subordinator. For those who see it as a prep, the constituent _when caught by fisherman_ is a PP headed by "when" whose complement is the non-finite subordinate clause _caught by fishermen_. For those who see "when" as a subordinator, it’s a subjectless non-finite subordinate clause (though the subject "sea trout" is easily retrievable from the matrix clause). Whichever analysis is preferred, the _when_- constituent is an adjunct in clause structure

Comment: @BillJ Your comment is unlikely to satisfy Jackie because it's not phrased in the jargon of SFG.  I can tell because your comment is coherent.  For instance, to answer her question about "the projecting clause", it will help to know that the originator of SFG says that "in projecting clauses the α clause expresses the ideational component of either locution, mental or factual projection; and the β clause carries
the ideational realisation of the projection."  Or maybe it won't help.

Comment: @deadrat  Ah, yes, that confused meaning-based mish-mash
based largely on Michael Halliday's thinking.

Comment: I am happy to have ANY feedback, really. Thank you both for your ideas.